# Access to MediaPlayer in Service from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, service, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

i'm writing music app. I have service with MediaPlayer which shows notification with custom view (play, next, back buttons). onClick reaction for these buttons was implemented using broadcasting. Is there a way to get access to MediaPlayer object from service, to use it in my broadcast receiver class? Or should I use bind service?

My Receiver class:

```
class PlayerNotificationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {


        if(intent != null) {
            val intentAction = intent.action
            when(intentAction){
                "PLAY_ACTION" -> {
                    // HOW TO GET ACCESS TO MEDIA PLAYER IN SERVICE ?????
                    Toast.makeText(context, "PLAY_ACTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    // TODO Change image button image in fragment

                }
                "BACK_ACTION" -> {
                    // TODO Notification back button implementation
                    Toast.makeText(context, "BACK_ACTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
                "NEXT_ACTION" -> {
                    // TODO Notification next button implementation
                    Toast.makeText(context, "NEXT_ACTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
                "PAUSE_ACTION" -> {
                    // TODO Notification pause button implementation
                    Toast.makeText(context, "PAUSE_ACTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
            }
        }

    } 
}
```

My Service class:

```
class PlayerService: Service() {

private var song: Int = 0

var songDuration: Long = 0

private lateinit var playerNotificationReceiver: PlayerNotificationReceiver

private val intentRequestCode: Int = 0
private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
private var isPlaying: Boolean = false


override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
   return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    // Broadcast receiver

    playerNotificationReceiver = PlayerNotificationReceiver()
    // Registering broadcast receiver
    registerReceiver(playerNotificationReceiver, IntentFilter(getString(R.string.PLAY_ACTION)))
    registerReceiver(playerNotificationReceiver, IntentFilter(getString(R.string.PAUSE_ACTION)))
    registerReceiver(playerNotificationReceiver, IntentFilter(getString(R.string.BACK_ACTION)))
    registerReceiver(playerNotificationReceiver, IntentFilter(getString(R.string.NEXT_ACTION)))


    song = intent?.getIntExtra("song", 0) ?: R.raw.taco_hemingway_europa

    // onStartCommand implementation
    if (!isPlaying) {

        // Creating pending intent for notification
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            intentRequestCode,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        // Pending intent with broadcast for custom view back button on  click
        val nextIntent = Intent(getString(R.string.NEXT_ACTION))
        nextIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        val nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        // Pending intent with broadcast for custom view back button on  click
        val backIntent = Intent(getString(R.string.BACK_ACTION))
        backIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        val backPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, backIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        // Pending intent with broadcast for custom view back button on  click
        val playIntent = Intent(getString(R.string.PLAY_ACTION))
        playIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        val playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        // Remote view
        val playerNotificationLayout = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.player_small_notification)

        val playerNotificationLayoutExpanded = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.player_large_notification)

        // Building notification with custom view
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PLAYER_CHANNEL)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_notification_icon)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(playerNotificationLayout)
            .setCustomBigContentView(playerNotificationLayoutExpanded)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Name")

        // Setting custom view button on click reaction
        playerNotificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notificationPlayButton, playPendingIntent)
        playerNotificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notificationBackButton, backPendingIntent)
        playerNotificationLayout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notificationNextButton, nextPendingIntent)

        // Notification manager
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        // Creating notification
        val  notification = notificationBuilder.build()

        // Post a notification to be shown in the status bar.
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification)


        // Creating media player and starting music - service main task
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, song)
        //mediaPlayer.start()
        //isPlaying = true
        //songDuration = mediaPlayer.duration.toLong()


        // Starting Service
        startForeground(1, notification)
    }

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    // Stop playing music and set isPlaying to false
    mediaPlayer.stop()
    isPlaying = false

    // Unregistering broadcast receiver
    unregisterReceiver(playerNotificationReceiver)
}
```

My fragment class:

```
class PlayerFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var playerServiceIntent: Intent

private var isPlaying: Boolean = false

// Animation lazy initalization
private val rotateAnimation by lazy { AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), R.anim.player_button_rotation) }

// Binding
private var _binding: FragmentPlayerBinding? = null
private val binding
    get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // playerServiceIntent
    playerServiceIntent = Intent(activity , PlayerService::class.java)
    playerServiceIntent.putExtra("song", R.raw.taco_hemingway_europa)

    // Starting service
    requireActivity().startService(playerServiceIntent)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    _binding = FragmentPlayerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // playerServiceIntent
    playerServiceIntent = Intent(activity , PlayerService::class.java)
    playerServiceIntent.putExtra("song", R.raw.taco_hemingway_europa)

    // Starting service
    requireActivity().startService(playerServiceIntent)

    binding.playerPlayButton.setOnClickListener {
        if(isPlaying){

            // Pending intent with broadcast for custom view play button on click
            val playIntent = Intent(getString(R.string.PLAY_ACTION))
            playIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
            val backPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            binding.playerPlayButton.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.pause_button, null))

        } else {
            // Pending intent with broadcast for custom view pause button on click
            val pauseIntent = Intent(getString(R.string.PAUSE_ACTION))
            pauseIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
            val backPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, pauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            binding.playerPlayButton.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.play_button, null))

            // TODO Start animation
            //binding.playerPlayButton.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
        }
    }

    // TODO Time bar implementation
    /*
    Timer implementation
    val timer = Timer()
    if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying){
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask {
            currentPosition = mediaPlayer.currentPosition.toLong()
            binding.textView.text = currentPosition.toString()
        },0,1000)
    } else {
        timer.cancel()
        timer.purge()
    }
    */
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    _binding = null
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A `BroadcastReceiver` is short lived. You cannot bind to a `Service` in a `BroadcastReceiver`, as binding is an asynchronous process and your `BroadcastReceiver` will be gone before the binding completes.

You can request that the `Service` do something by calling `startService()` with an `Intent` that has some ACTION in it that tells the `Service` what you want to do.

Or you can just change your notification so that the actions go directly to the `Service` instead of going via your `BroadcastReceiver`.

---

As an alternative, (this is kinda hacky), you could store the `MediaPlayer` refrerence in a `public static` (global) variable and then you could use it directly from your `BroadcastReceiver`. This is not the recommended approach, but it does work.